# How could I check if a particular ViewController is on the UINavigationController stack?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a main that links to a second view by a button and links back via a 'back' button in the navigation bar. I want to hide the navigation bar in the main view and only show it in the scene view.

I have hidden the navigation bar on the main view and on first launch it looks fine but as soon as the second view is popped off the stack there is an empty navigation bar on the main view.

Is there any way to detect if the main view is currently visible and then hide the navigation bar whenever it is? Or any other fixes to the problem I'm having?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: View or view controller?

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES(NO) hide or not in viewWillAppear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this slightly the wrong way. Instead of looking for a particular view controller on the stack and changing it's properties, do it directly inside the two view controllers. Use the  `viewWillAppear:` and `viewWillDisappear:` methods:

First (top) view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Second (child) view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

The code in the child view controller is optional, and if you have further child view controllers, you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

This will run through the view controllers in your navigationController stack. Once you find your class kind, do whatever you have to do with it!

```
for ( UIViewController *vc in [self.navigationController viewControllers]) {
      if ([vc isKindOfClass:[YourClass class]]) {
             // do something
      }
}
```

EDIT

This will check if your mainviewcontroller is being presented:

```
if ([[self.navigationController topViewController] isKindOfClass:[yourmainviewcontroller class]]){
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}else{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain, I'm having trouble understanding what you mean?

Comment: Try what I wrote now in my answer, after `EDIT`.